# How to split a list In the form of array?

Tags: python, list

I want to separate the arrays that were paired in the list one by one.

For example see the below list:

```
data = [
    'id_code:3211238576;birth_year:1350;born_in:Boushehr',
    'id_code:9801233575;born_in:Argentina;birth_year:1360',
    'born_in:Portugal;id_code:0219206431;birth_year:1358',
    'id_code:0021678913;born_in:Shiraz;birth_year:1120',
    'id_code:1101102135;born_in:Gilan;birth_year:1152',

]
```

I want the list to be separated as follows:

```
data = [
    'id_code:3211238576','birth_year:1350',
    'born_in:Boushehr','id_code:9801233575','born_in:Argentina',
    'birth_year:1360','born_in:Portugal','id_code:0219206431',
    'birth_year:1358','id_code:0021678913','born_in:Shiraz',
    'birth_year:1120','id_code:1101102135','born_in:Gilan','birth_year:1152'
]
```

my code for this work:

```
m = [','.join(sorted(i.split(';'))) for i in data]
print(m)
```

My output code(wrong answer):

```
['birth_year:1350,born_in:Boushehr,id_code:3211238576', 'birth_year:1360,born_in:Argentina,id_code:9801233575', 'birth_year:1358,born_in:Portugal,id_code:0219206431', 'birth_year:1120,born_in:Shiraz,id_code:0021678913', 'birth_year:1152,born_in:Gilan,id_code:1101102135']
```

The code I wrote gives the wrong output, please help me correct the output

Comment: Does https://treyhunner.com/2015/12/python-list-comprehensions-now-in-color/ help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to use list comprehension:

First split your strings in list of strings:

```
t = [i.split(';') for i in data]
```

Then flatten your lists

```
res = [item for sublist in t for item in sublist]
```

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work because when you just replace ";" by ","...
You should do something like this :

```
data1 = [] # New list
for i in data :
   x = i.split(';')
   for e in x :
       data1 += [e]
```

The problem is that you split your string to join it again in one piece ⚠

(zanga has proposed a version with list comprehension but it is the same method)

Answer (score 0):

Why use join? When you call join it returns a string that contains ",", not a list. I believe this is what you want

```
    res = list()
    for i in data:
        res.extend(i.split(";"))
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is the `",".join` part.  Without it, you are almost there:

```
>>> [sorted(i.split(';')) for i in data]
[['birth_year:1350', 'born_in:Boushehr', 'id_code:3211238576'], ['birth_year:1360', 'born_in:Argentina', 'id_code:9801233575'], ['birth_year:1358', 'born_in:Portugal', 'id_code:0219206431'], ['birth_year:1120', 'born_in:Shiraz', 'id_code:0021678913'], ['birth_year:1152', 'born_in:Gilan', 'id_code:1101102135']]
```

but then the join takes each of the lists within a list and turns it into a string...

What you really want to do is turn them into one big list

First, we can remove the `sorted` from what we have, because sorting each sublist doesn't really help us:

```
>>> [i.split(';') for i in data]
[['id_code:3211238576', 'birth_year:1350', 'born_in:Boushehr'], ['id_code:9801233575', 'born_in:Argentina', 'birth_year:1360'], ['born_in:Portugal', 'id_code:0219206431', 'birth_year:1358'], ['id_code:0021678913', 'born_in:Shiraz', 'birth_year:1120'], ['id_code:1101102135', 'born_in:Gilan', 'birth_year:1152']]
```

Now to combine them into a single list:

I would start with an old fashioned loop in this case before trying to compress it:

```
list_of_lists = [i.split(';') for i in data]
final_list = []
for partial_list in list_of_lists:
  final_list += partial_list # add each set of entries to the new full list
print(final_list)
```

and then maybe sort it in place

```
final_list.sort()
print(final_list)
```

the other ways that don't modify variables or add items to existing list variables are much nicer, but when I am stuck, I usually attack it the old fashioned way, and then wrap everything in a function to isolate all my temporary variables from the rest of the program.

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of `chain.iterable()` to flatten the list as follows:

```
from itertools import chain

data = [
    'id_code:3211238576;birth_year:1350;born_in:Boushehr',
    'id_code:9801233575;born_in:Argentina;birth_year:1360',
    'born_in:Portugal;id_code:0219206431;birth_year:1358',
    'id_code:0021678913;born_in:Shiraz;birth_year:1120',
    'id_code:1101102135;born_in:Gilan;birth_year:1152',
]

m = list(chain.from_iterable([i.split(';') for i in data]))
print(m)
```

**Output:**

```
['id_code:3211238576', 'birth_year:1350', 'born_in:Boushehr', 'id_code:9801233575', 'born_in:Argentina', 'birth_year:1360', 'born_in:Portugal', 'id_code:0219206431', 'birth_year:1358', 'id_code:0021678913', 'born_in:Shiraz', 'birth_year:1120', 'id_code:1101102135', 'born_in:Gilan', 'birth_year:1152']
```

Answer (score 0):

here you go

```
data = [
    'id_code:3211238576;birth_year:1350;born_in:Boushehr',
    'id_code:9801233575;born_in:Argentina;birth_year:1360',
    'born_in:Portugal;id_code:0219206431;birth_year:1358',
    'id_code:0021678913;born_in:Shiraz;birth_year:1120',
    'id_code:1101102135;born_in:Gilan;birth_year:1152',
]
w=[]
for i in data : 
    x=i.split(';')
    for e in x:
        w.append(e)

print(w)
```

and you can use `replace` function insted if the nested loop

```
for i in data:
w += i.replace(';',' ').split()
```